# For sets $A$ and $B,$ prove $(A\setminus B) = A\cap B^c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For sets A and B,(A\B) = A∩B^c

show that (A\B)\C ⊆ A(B\C) without using Venn Diagrams
show that A∩B and B\A are disjoint without using Venn Diagrams

Need explanation to solve this sum. Cheeers!

Comment: This use of notation such as $A(X)$ for sets $A$, $X$ is unfamiliar - what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Suppose $A\cap B$ and $B\setminus A$ have a common element $x$.

Then $x$ is in $A$ and $B$, since $x\in A\cap B$. Does this produce a contradiction?

If it does it means the two sets do not have any common element, thus they are disjoint.